# Multiple CssLayouts within VerticalLayout

Tags: java, html, css, vaadin

I have attached two views of my screen, one is the normal view while the other is when I resize my browser window(or when wrapping takes place).I am using Vaadin , I have multiple CssLayouts within a VerticalLayout.

[image: Normal_View]

[image: Disturbed_View]

What actually I am doing is I have a UI class extends CssLayout providing general functionality that I have some items in a drop down. When any of the item is selected , a label is added showing that item is selected,having a cross button which removes the label means that the selection is cancelled. The items will be wrapped when reach the end of the width.

I need the above functionality mutiple times so I am placing these CssLayouts in a Vertical layout which is inside a Panel,therefore, when the height of that vertical layout exceeds the panel's height scroll bars will appear which is fine.

Now the issue is the wrapping, as shown in the view.Due to the presence of multiple CssLayouts .What is desired is that when any css layout wraps the layout below moves down so that they'll not overlap ,as they are doing right now.

Code where I am adding these Css Layouts

```
public class ProcessUserSelectionPanel extends Panel
{

private List<SelectorUI> processUserSelectors = new ArrayList<SelectorUI>();
private static int SELECTION_LAYOUT_HEIGHT = 38;
private static int MAX_PANEL_HEIGHT = 200;
private VerticalLayout innerLayout ;



protected void initUI() 
{
    addStyleName("u-proc-user-panel");
    setHeight(MAX_PANEL_HEIGHT,Component.UNITS_PIXELS);
    innerLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    innerLayout.addStyleName("u-proc-user-panel");
    innerLayout.setWidth(100, Component.UNITS_PERCENTAGE);
    innerLayout.setMargin(true);
    setContent(innerLayout);

}

public void updateSelectorPanels(){
    innerLayout.removeAllComponents();
    processUserSelectors.clear();
    int  task = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++){

            SelectorUI processUserSelector = new SelectorUI();

            processUserSelectors.add(processUserSelector);
            innerLayout.addComponent(processUserSelector);  
            task++;
        }
    }
    innerLayout.setHeight((task+1)*SELECTION_LAYOUT_HEIGHT,Component.UNITS_PIXELS );
    if((task+1)*SELECTION_LAYOUT_HEIGHT < MAX_PANEL_HEIGHT){
        setHeight((task+1)*SELECTION_LAYOUT_HEIGHT+5, Component.UNITS_PIXELS);
    }
    else{
        setHeight(MAX_PANEL_HEIGHT,Component.UNITS_PIXELS);
    }
}
```

Css classes I have used for the label ( having text and cross icon) inside Css layout

.u-selector-panel-big-label{
        margin-right:5px;
        margin-bottom:5px;
        display:inline-block;
        border:solid;
        border-width:thin;
        border-color:rgb(216, 216, 216);
        background-color: #EBE2FF;/*#D0C4F0; */
        pointer-events: none;
    }

```
.u-selector-panel-heading{
    margin-right:20px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:inline-block;
/*  pointer-events: none; */
    width:150px;
}

.u-selector-panel-text-label{
    margin-right:15px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: #EBE2FF;/*#D0C4F0; */
    pointer-events: none;
}

.u-selector-panel-icon-label{
    text-align: center;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: #EBE2FF;
    pointer-events: all;
}

.v-csslayout-container .v-filterselect  {
    margin-top: 2px;
    display:inline-flex;
    height: 1.49em;
}
```

May be I am missing something or not using these correctly.Any help to solve this issue is appreciated.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the width in percentage instead of pixels.

Comment: I am not specifying width any where ,Css layout handling this wraping itself

Comment: i have added some part of code may be helpful to get an idea ,actually the code is quite large to paste here

Answer (score 1):

There is an addon called [Tokenfield](http://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/46) which does solve the functionality you are looking at. Why don't you have look at it? It works great and awesome. Try it if doesn't solve your problem, just let me I will have a look in to it.

Comment: ok sure I will look at it, thnx for this, will accept your answer if  my problem get solved....

Comment: sure check it out, if you have questions regarding the same please let me know

Comment: hey Patton , I gave a look at online demo didn't get a chance to work with code, the very first thing I observed is that when I re-size the browser window sometimes the input control and some of the tags got vanish(when wrapping occurred), this issue is nearly similar to my problem except that my view get disturbed and here view looks fine but tags and input disappeared.. what do u suggest about this , i mean what exactly causing this??

Comment: Even I tried, it seems to work perfectly fine, which browser? what is the layout you have used I mean which part of the component?